# Javascript form not working/not calculating result from a formula

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a JavaScript form that will calculate feeding volume based off the feed type, amount of times the feed that will be given in a day, target protein intake,the current protein intake, and the patient's weight.

The form shows up fine in HTML terms, but the script is not working because it doesn't calculate. I tried debugging using chrome, but I didn't get any errors.

Here is my script:

```
var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];



 var Formula = new Array();
    Formula["0.016"] = 0.016;
    Formula["0.009"] = 0.009;
    Formula["0.017"] = 0.017;
    Formula["0.024"] = 0.024;
    Formula["0.035"] = 0.035;
    Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
    Formula["0.019"] = 0.019;
    Formula["0.026"] = 0.026;
    Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
    Formula["0.02"] = 0.02;
Formula["0.0255"] = 0.0255;
Formula["0.0142"] = 0.0142;
Formula["0.0181"] = 0.0181;
Formula["0.0195"] = 0.0195;
Formula["0.0216"] = 0.0216;
Formula["0.0268"] = 0.0268;
Formula["0.028"] = 0.028;
function getFormulaType() {
    var formulatype = 0;

    var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

    var selectedFormula = theForm.elements["Formula"];


    formulatype = Formula[selectedFormula.value];


    return formulatype;
}
var Times = new Array();
Times["6"] = 6;
Times["7"] = 7;
Times["8"] = 8;
function getFeedTimes() {
    var Feedtimes = 0;


    var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

    var Selectedtimes = theForm.elements["feedtimes"];


    Selectedtimes = Formula[Feedtimes.value];


    return Selectedtimes;
}
var targetintake = new Array();
targetintake["3.5"] = 3.5;
targetintake["4"] = 4;
targetintake["4.5"] = 4.5;

function getTarget() {
    var target = 0;


    var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

    var selectedTarget = theForm.elements["targetintake"];


    target = Formula[selectedTarget.value];


    return target;

}
function getWeight() {

    var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

    var Weight = theForm.elements["Weight"];
    var weight = 0;

    if (Weight.value != "") {
        weight = parseFloat(Weight.value);
    }
    return weight;
}
function getVolume() {

    var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

    var Volume = theForm.elements["Volume"];
    var volume = 0;

    if (Volume.value != "") {
        Volume = parseFloat(Volume.value);
    }
    return volume;
}
function getProtein() {
    var E = 6 * getTarget();
    var D = 6000 * getFormulaType() * getVolume();
    var F = E - D;
    var Total = F / getFeedTimes();

    //display the result
    document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML =
                              Total


}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script> 
//the script posted above

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="proteinvolume">

        <p> Formula Type</p>
        <select id ="Formula"name="Formula" onchange="">
            <option value="0.016"> PreTerm Plain BM</option>
            <option value= "0.009">Term Plain BM </option>
            <option value="0.017">Term BM +Similac HiProtein HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.024">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.035">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Similac  HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.019">Term BM+Similac HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.026">Term BM+Similac HMF 26 cal/oz</option>
            <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.02">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0255">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0142">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 22  </option>
            <option value="0.0181">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare  24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0195">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 25 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0216">Term BM+Similac Special Care 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0268">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.028">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 27 cal/oz (1:1 SSC30:24) </option>
        </select>

        <br />


        <p>Number of feedings per day</p>
        <select id="feedtimes"name="feedtimes" onchange="">
            <option value= "6">6 </option>
            <option value="7">7 </option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
        <p>Target Protein Intake</p>
        <select id="targetintake"name="targetintake" onchange="">
            <option value="3.5">3.5 </option>
            <option value="4">4 </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <p>Patient Weight (grams)</p>
        <input type="text" id="Weight" name="Weight">
        <br />
        <p>Current Feeding Volume (mL)</p>
        <input type="text" id="Volume" name="Volume" onchange="getProtein();">
        <br />

        <button type="button" onsubmit="getProtein()">Calculate</button>
        Protein Volume per feed (mL):<INPUT type="text" id="feed" Size=8>



     </form>


</body>
</html>
```

It would mean a lot if someone could help me find the error, or could direct me on how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To add to what others already have, you should have the script run only after the document is completely loaded.

```
<body onload="runCalculations()">
```

Just put all your script code inside a

```
function runCalculations() {}
```

so that it runs after the document is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind with the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There's really just a lot wrong here.

First, it's easier / better / more cross-platform to do `document.getElementById('whatever')`; I tried your syntax in Chrome and the form elements were not being found.

Second, your getFeedTimes was trying to fetch the value from the Formula object, rather than the Times object that you created.  And using Feedtimes.value which was not defined.

Third, getWeight is never called. NOt sure where it's supposed to fit in.

Fourth, you had Volume when you meant volume.  Javascript is case sensitive.

I have working code here (though I don't know if the formula is actually right, it does pull in what you asked for).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script> 
var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];



 var Formula = new Array();
    Formula["0.016"] = 0.016;
    Formula["0.009"] = 0.009;
    Formula["0.017"] = 0.017;
    Formula["0.024"] = 0.024;
    Formula["0.035"] = 0.035;
    Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
    Formula["0.019"] = 0.019;
    Formula["0.026"] = 0.026;
    Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
    Formula["0.02"] = 0.02;
Formula["0.0255"] = 0.0255;
Formula["0.0142"] = 0.0142;
Formula["0.0181"] = 0.0181;
Formula["0.0195"] = 0.0195;
Formula["0.0216"] = 0.0216;
Formula["0.0268"] = 0.0268;
Formula["0.028"] = 0.028;
function getFormulaType() {
    var formulatype = 0;

    var selectedFormula = document.getElementById("Formula");
    formulatype = Formula[selectedFormula.value];

    return formulatype;
}
var Times = new Array();
Times["6"] = 6;
Times["7"] = 7;
Times["8"] = 8;
function getFeedTimes() {
    var Feedtimes = 0;

    var Feedtimes = document.getElementById("feedtimes");
    Selectedtimes = Times[Feedtimes.value];

    return Selectedtimes;
}
var targetintake = new Array();
targetintake["3.5"] = 3.5;
targetintake["4"] = 4;
targetintake["4.5"] = 4.5;

function getTarget() {
    var target = 0;

    var selectedTarget = document.getElementById("targetintake");

    target = targetintake[selectedTarget.value];
    return target;

}
function getWeight() {

    var Weight = document.getElementById("Weight");
    var weight = 0;

    if (Weight.value != "") {
        weight = parseFloat(Weight.value);
    }
    
    return weight;
}
function getVolume() {
    var Volume = document.getElementById("Volume");
    var volume = 0;

    if (Volume.value != "") {
        volume = parseFloat(Volume.value);
    }
    
    return volume;
}
function getProtein() {
    var E = 6 * getTarget();
    var D = 6000 * getFormulaType() * getVolume();
    var F = E - D;
    var Total = F / getFeedTimes();

    //display the result
    document.getElementById('feed').value = Total


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="proteinvolume">

        <p> Formula Type</p>
        <select id ="Formula" name="Formula" onchange="">
            <option value="0.016"> PreTerm Plain BM</option>
            <option value= "0.009">Term Plain BM </option>
            <option value="0.017">Term BM +Similac HiProtein HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.024">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.035">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Similac  HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.019">Term BM+Similac HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.026">Term BM+Similac HMF 26 cal/oz</option>
            <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 22 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.02">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0255">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0142">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 22  </option>
            <option value="0.0181">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare  24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0195">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 25 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0216">Term BM+Similac Special Care 26 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.0268">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 24 cal/oz </option>
            <option value="0.028">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 27 cal/oz (1:1 SSC30:24) </option>
        </select>

        <br />


        <p>Number of feedings per day</p>
        <select id="feedtimes" name="feedtimes" onchange="">
            <option value= "6">6 </option>
            <option value="7">7 </option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
        <p>Target Protein Intake</p>
        <select id="targetintake" name="targetintake" onchange="">
            <option value="3.5">3.5 </option>
            <option value="4">4 </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <p>Patient Weight (grams)</p>
        <input type="text" id="patientWeight" name="Weight">
        <br />
        <p>Current Feeding Volume (mL)</p>
        <input type="text" id="Volume" name="Volume" onchange="getProtein();">
        <br />

        <button type="button" onclick="getProtein()">Calculate</button>
        Protein Volume per feed (mL):<INPUT type="text" id="feed" Size=8>



     </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing. Out of curiosity, why build all those associative arrays rather than just calling `parseFloat` or `parseInt` on the value of the element, where the element values are just string representations of the number?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one major issue -- I'm going to turn your code into a snippet and see if it runs.

You have your script in your `head` element and it runs as soon as the page starts loading.

```
var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];
```

will be `null` because none of the forms appear yet.  Your code should be just before the closing `</body>` tag.

The first step of debugging should always be checking the JavaScript error console.  If there are no errors, use the debugger to start walking through the code and ensuring the values are, indeed, what you expect.

In addition, you are doing

```
<button type="button" onsubmit="getProtein()">Calculate</button>
```

buttons do not have an `onsubmit` property, forms do.  Either move this to the form *or* change it to `onclick`.

That should be enough to get you along to further debugging.

Oh, just as a note:  You aren't really using arrays in your code:

```
var Formula = new Array();
```

should be

var Formula = {}; // an empty object.

In order to get the magical aspect of arrays, you have to be using *integer* keys.  What you have kinda-sorta works because arrays *do* inherit from *object*, and thus can be used like an object.  This "works" until you treat them like an array. ;)

```js
var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];


var Formula = new Array();
Formula["0.016"] = 0.016;
Formula["0.009"] = 0.009;
Formula["0.017"] = 0.017;
Formula["0.024"] = 0.024;
Formula["0.035"] = 0.035;
Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
Formula["0.019"] = 0.019;
Formula["0.026"] = 0.026;
Formula["0.0145"] = 0.0145;
Formula["0.02"] = 0.02;
Formula["0.0255"] = 0.0255;
Formula["0.0142"] = 0.0142;
Formula["0.0181"] = 0.0181;
Formula["0.0195"] = 0.0195;
Formula["0.0216"] = 0.0216;
Formula["0.0268"] = 0.0268;
Formula["0.028"] = 0.028;

function getFormulaType() {
  var formulatype = 0;

  var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

  var selectedFormula = theForm.elements["Formula"];


  formulatype = Formula[selectedFormula.value];


  return formulatype;
}
var Times = new Array();
Times["6"] = 6;
Times["7"] = 7;
Times["8"] = 8;

function getFeedTimes() {
  var Feedtimes = 0;


  var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

  var Selectedtimes = theForm.elements["feedtimes"];


  Selectedtimes = Formula[Feedtimes.value];


  return Selectedtimes;
}
var targetintake = new Array();
targetintake["3.5"] = 3.5;
targetintake["4"] = 4;
targetintake["4.5"] = 4.5;

function getTarget() {
  var target = 0;


  var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

  var selectedTarget = theForm.elements["targetintake"];


  target = Formula[selectedTarget.value];


  return target;

}

function getWeight() {

  var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

  var Weight = theForm.elements["Weight"];
  var weight = 0;

  if (Weight.value != "") {
    weight = parseFloat(Weight.value);
  }
  return weight;
}

function getVolume() {

  var theForm = document.forms["proteinvolume"];

  var Volume = theForm.elements["Volume"];
  var volume = 0;

  if (Volume.value != "") {
    Volume = parseFloat(Volume.value);
  }
  return volume;
}

function getProtein() {
  
  var E = 6 * getTarget();
  var D = 6000 * getFormulaType() * getVolume();
  var F = E - D;
  var Total = F / getFeedTimes();

  //display the result
  document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML =
    Total


}
```

```html
<form action="" id="proteinvolume">

  <p>Formula Type</p>
  <select id="Formula" name="Formula" onchange="">
    <option value="0.016">PreTerm Plain BM</option>
    <option value="0.009">Term Plain BM</option>
    <option value="0.017">Term BM +Similac HiProtein HMF 22 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.024">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 24 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.035">Term BM+Similac HiProtein HMF 26 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Similac HMF 22 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.019">Term BM+Similac HMF 24 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.026">Term BM+Similac HMF 26 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0145">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 22 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.02">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 24 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0255">Term BM+Enfamil HMF 26 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0142">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 22</option>
    <option value="0.0181">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 24 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0195">Term BM+SimilacSpecialCare 25 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0216">Term BM+Similac Special Care 26 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.0268">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 24 cal/oz</option>
    <option value="0.028">SimilacSpecialCare HiProtein 27 cal/oz (1:1 SSC30:24)</option>
  </select>

  <br />


  <p>Number of feedings per day</p>
  <select id="feedtimes" name="feedtimes" onchange="">
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
  </select>
  <p>Target Protein Intake</p>
  <select id="targetintake" name="targetintake" onchange="">
    <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <p>Patient Weight (grams)</p>
  <input type="text" id="Weight" name="Weight">
  <br />
  <p>Current Feeding Volume (mL)</p>
  <input type="text" id="Volume" name="Volume" onchange="getProtein();">
  <br />

  <button type="button" onclick="getProtein()">Calculate</button>
  Protein Volume per feed (mL):
  <INPUT type="text" id="feed" Size=8>



</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I'll definitely take your advice on the array usage!